# Migrated question not linked to my account

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, migration

This [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/security-of-using-passwords-or-even-passphrases-to-encrypt-files) was migrated to IT Security 2 days ago. Is there some way to associate my answer to it with the user ID I just created?

Comment: User has a Security.SE account has posted other answers. This answer did not automatically tie ownership back to him. Case of other validly tie answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/is-this-much-distrust-really-nessesary/7432#7432

Comment: Looks like it is associated correctly...? Can you please check again?

Comment: @AviD, it is now associated correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sign in with the ID that was used to create that question. It will connect between sites. After that, you can request that this account and the account used to ask the question be merged.

Comment: I'm currently logged in with the same openid that I use on all the stack exchange sites. This was migrated before I had an id  on this site.